# Reddit bot - either bypass or click "yes" to over 18 check?

Tags: c#, bots, reddit

I am making a Reddit comment bot that will crawl subreddits as it finds links in the pages. My problem is that when I try to crawl NSFW subreddits with an 18+ age question, despite clicking "yes" in my normal browser, Reddit returns a 18+ age question every time the C# bot hits those pages.

Is there a way to avoid this or to click the "yes" button programatically?

Comment: Does reddit allow doing so according their ToS?

Comment: There are plenty of Reddit comment bots, so yes I think so.

Comment: presence of something does not mean it's allowed. **Does reddit allow to do what you're doing or you're stealing their content?** For automatic requests there is API: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

Comment: Reddit do provide an API for doing stuff like this and people have written bots. None-the-less @zerkms is correct, presence is not justification for it's existence.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is a way, look at the HTML form for the question:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="pretty-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="uh" value="">
        <p>are you over eighteen and willing to see adult content?</p>
        <p>
        <button type="submit" name="over18" value="yes">yes</button>
        <button type="submit" name="over18" value="no">no</button>
        </p>
</form>
```

You could fill out the values and then submit the POST request.